# the results is repeated in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, javascript-databinding

when I use the || in data-bind, it repeats the results when both are true, but separately work fine,

I tried in many ways and all give me the same and when I use with === no results return and without parentheses is the same result

```
<div data-bind="visible: (
  worktask.wbc_date == $root.FirstViewOnlyDate() || 
  worktask.wbc_date == null
)">
```

Comment: Please show us what you did - add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `FirstViewOnlyDate` is an observable, did you try:

```
visible: (
  !worktask.wbc_date() && 
   worktask.wbc_date !== $root.FirstViewOnlyDate()
)
```

?